# Add Values to List<string> in C#

Tags: c#

I'm very new to C#, I'm printing the below data on a console via `foreach` loop. The data is coming as below:

```
COLUMN1 Ajay   
COLUMN2 Mahesh  
COLUMN3 Patresh  
COLUMN4 WaterBottle  
COLUMN5 Laptop Keyboard

COLUMN1 98-0192371  
COLUMN2 51-0112321  
COLUMN3 51-0112320  
COLUMN4 94-3200380  
COLUMN5 51-0300635

COLUMN1 0.008453  
COLUMN2 NONE  
COLUMN3 0.008400  
COLUMN4 NONE
```

I need to convert this to a dictionary like below for all 5 data, if a column is not found then print "Null".

```
{
   "Column1":{Ajay, 98-0192371, 0.008453}
}
```

The below code is printing the data:

```
List<string> fields = new List<string>();
Dictionary<string, List<string>> keyValuePairs = new();

foreach (var item in customFields)
{
    var content = item.Value.AsDictionary();
    foreach (var field in content)
    {    
        Console.WriteLine(field.Key + " " + field.Value.Content.Replace("\n", ""));
    }
}
```

I'm having a hard time adding data to the dictionary. So asking for some suggestions here on how to do it.

Comment: I have removed it. Thank You

Comment: Are you allowed to / comfortable with using Linq statements to achieve this?

Comment: What is the type of `customFields`?

Comment: it is IReadOnlyList

Comment: A `IReadOnlyList<T>` has an inner type `T`. That's what we need to know. It seems your working with the Azure AI FromRecognizer and `customeFields` is the value of a [`AnalyzedDocument.Fields`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.ai.formrecognizer.documentanalysis.analyzeddocument.fields?view=azure-dotnet#azure-ai-formrecognizer-documentanalysis-analyzeddocument-fields). Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, Correct, I'm getting the rows and column values separately when i loop through them.

Comment: Then that may be a better starting point.

Comment: Your expected output model is invalid. Do you actually mean `"Column1": [ "Ajay", "98-0192371", "0.008453" ]`? I.e. you want to group all values from the same column together in a list?

Comment: Yes , Basically Dictionary<string, List<string>>

Answer (score 0):

So as commented you want a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` as result where the keys are `COLUMN1` ... `COLUMN5` and the values are what [`AsDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.ai.formrecognizer.documentanalysis.documentfieldvalue.asdictionary?view=azure-dotnet) returned as values. If a column was not found i would not add a `null` list(as desired) but an empty list.

You could use this LINQ Query:

```
ILookup<string, string> colLookup = customFields
    .SelectMany(cf => cf.Value.AsDictionary())
    .ToLookup(kv => kv.Key, kv => kv.Value);

Dictionary<string, List<string>> resultDict = Enumerable
    .Range(1, 5).Select(i => $"Column{i}")
    .ToDictionary(col => col, col => colLookup[col].ToList());
```

If you want distinct values you simply have to use `Distinct` before `ToList`.